# Memory Leaks in NODEJS With Chrome-DevTools - Get variables that are causing memory leaks and App to crush?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, memory, memory-leaks

We're experiencing crushes with our NODEJS app , for some reason we have somewhere in the code some variables that are not getting released , and they should be.

For that we've decided using Chrome DevTools and take snapshots.

However I can't seem to find the source for the memory that's not getting released in seconds 6 , 12 and 14 , here in the red circles:

[image]

Any idea how can we find the root cause for the blue lines ?

Comment: code, if there's a memory leak, it's in badly written code

Comment: @Bravo: I know , I need to find that code and those variables that are not getting released.Can you explain how to find them ?

Comment: Oh, right, no. Debugging code is hard, debugging code based on an image of memory usage is pretty much impossible

Comment: @Bravo: It's a big goddamn code , how can I narrow down and limit my search ? I need a profiler that somehow can detect that.What's my best bet , Bravo ?

Comment: so, it's nodejs code, and you're debugging with a browser? that's pretty cool, didn't realise chrome can debug nodejs - let me refamiliarise myself with chrome developer tools - hopefully someone else will come along with better insight than I have for the moemnt

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the memory is actually being released since the memory use goes down after a brief spike. It looks to me that this is more like a high instant need for memory then a memory leak. Try to correlate this with the logs and see what was happening at that time. From the picture you posted you seem to have a lot of strings and arrays in memory.